# Can a NSPersistentStore safely be opened twice?

Tags: core-data, nspersistentstore

As a regular safety background task in my app, I have to save my `NSManagedObjectContext` with the *SaveAs...* method called `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:`. However, this method removes the storefrom the coordinator and adds the new store. This is fatal because my complete UI is based on objects loaded from the old store. Reloading the UI is no option because the user may be working deep within the UI and currently editing objects loaded from the old store.

My idea is to bring up a second stack of coordinator, moc and so on and let this duplicate perform the migration. Can a `NSPersistentStore` be safely opened (*readOnly*) by a second coordinator? My guess is not. I don't understand why Apple didn't add an option to keep the original store after the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your store is a `SQLite` store then yes you can open as many `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instances as you want.  If you are not using a `SQLite` store then I would not recommend it.

However, if you are doing a back-up, is there a reason you are not copying the file using `NSFileManager` instead?  Should be significantly faster than a migration.  Fast enough that you could safely lock the store during the copy.

Comment: I need to get rid of iCloud metadata and I'd like to have all in one file (journaling mode). Therefor, I used migration. What way would you go?

Comment: Take a look at this sample app which includes a switch for making a backup when the app is launched or when it becomes active.  Not sure it adds anything of value to your approach but you never know. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: @Norbert Fair enough, then doing a migration makes sense and my answer stands.  You can definitely open a second core data stack to handle the backup and it will not impact your UI stack at all.